# Error importing futures python

Tags: python, python-2.7, streaming, python-import, torrent

I'm trying to use this module [`SimpleTorrentStreaming`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SimpleTorrentStreaming/0.1.0) To stream torrent with python however when I try to

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
>>> from SimpleTorrentStreaming import SimpleTorrentStreaming
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SimpleTorrentStreaming/SimpleTorrentStreaming.py", line 7, in <module>
    from futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
ImportError: No module named futures
```

Which tell me to install the [`futures`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures/3.0.3) module, and I did:

```
$ pip freeze
....
futures==3.0.3
....
```

However I still getting the same error. I do really need to get this working since this is the **only** python library for torrent streaming.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same interpreter for both operations?

Comment: Yes I'm sure since I can `import SimpleTorrentStreaming`. But tell me if they are another way to be certain.

Comment: Thanks @SDilmac It solve the my problem.

Comment: @SDilmac you should post this as an answer

Comment: @SDilmac It is not about points, it is about indicating, that a question has a solution. Future users who will face the very same problem most likely will skip this question thinking, that there is no answer.

Comment: @SDilmac if you do not want to post an answer yourself, I will do it and mark it as Community Wiki as suggested per [this Meta answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598/471899).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `SimpleTorrentStreaming.py` file and replace this line

```
from futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
```

with

```
from concurrent.futures import *
```

Answer (score 2):

Author of SimpleTorrentStreaming here.

I split that library out of another project a long time ago, and for some reason I left it abandoned, hoping that nobody would get to the bottom of my github repository list until I had time to finish it.

I've released a new version (0.1.1), that actually works.

https://github.com/XayOn/python-simpletorrentstreaming
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SimpleTorrentStreaming/0.1.1